# Skype4py attach does not work

Tags: python, windows-7, skype4py

I am having trouble with getting Skype4Py to attach to my Skype client.  I downloaded easy _install and used it to install Skype4Py.  I have 64bit Python and windows 7.  When I try the example script (seen below) line by line using the IDLE, I can't get past the `skype.attach()`, nothing seems to happen.  I end up having to close the IDLE and kill the application.  If you have any ideas please let me know.  I apologize in advance.  Just figuring out how to download Skype4Py was challenging for me. Skype is running and I am logged in.

```
import Skype4Py

# Create an instance of the Skype class.
skype = Skype4Py.Skype()

# Connect the Skype object to the Skype client.
skype.Attach()

# Obtain some information from the client and print it out.
print 'Your full name:', skype.CurrentUser.FullName
print 'Your contacts:'
for user in skype.Friends:
    print '    ', user.FullName
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently looks like 64-bit Python is not supported, because Skype the client application is 32-bit.

https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py/issues/6

Use 32-bit Python.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was totally stumped on why it wasn't working, but 32-bit worked for me as well.

Comment: 3 years later. Did you check if its working in windows 10?